# Train SyntaxNet model

Tags: nlp, tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet

I am trying to train the Google Syntaxnet model in a different language using the datasets available at http://universaldependencies.org/ and following this [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet#detailed-tutorial-building-an-nlp-pipeline-with-syntaxnet). I edited the `syntaxnet/context.pbtxt` file but when I try to run the `bazel's script` provided in the guide I got the following error:

```
syntaxnet/term_frequency_map.cc:62] Check failed: ::tensorflow::Status::OK() == (tensorflow::Env::Default()->NewRandomAccessFile(filename, &file)) (OK vs. Not found: brain_pos/greedy/0/label-map)
```

My doubt is: I have to provide this file and the other files such as `fine-to-universal.map`, `tag-map`, `word-map` and so on, or the train step have to create them using the training dataset? And if I have to provide them, how can I build them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thing as you and ran into the exact same error. It turned out that I accidentally removed the flag `--compute_lexicon`. I suppose that this flag takes care of creating `tag-map`, `word-map` etc. So just make sure that `--compute_lexicon` is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Well I got a similar error and to be honest I didn't find out what was the problem but I used this [link](https://github.com/dsindex/syntaxnet) to learn the training and testing process and it  provides useful documantation for training.

you might not change the format of training, tuning and test datasets from `.conllu` to `.conl` or training shell maybe confused by the directories which are mentioned in `--arg_prefix`, `--output_path` , --task_context or even `--model_path`

Answer (score 0):

I recall having a similar error at the beginning. Did you use the exact code under 'training a parser step 1: local pretraining'? Because you will notice there's an uninitialized $PARAMS variable in there that is supposed to represent the parameters of your trained POS tagger. When you train a tagger (see earlier in the same tutorial), it will create files in models/brain_pos/greedy/$PARAMS. I believe that in your case, this $PARAMS variable was interpreted as 0 and the script is looking for a trained tagger in brain_pos/greedy/0 which it obviously does not find. If you just add a line at the beginning of the script that specifies the parameters of a trained tagger (128-0.08-3600-0.9-0 in the tutorial) it should work.

Thus:

```
$PARAMS=128-0.08-3600-0.9-0
bazel-bin/syntaxnet/parser_trainer \
  --arg_prefix=brain_parser \
  --batch_size=32 \
  --projectivize_training_set \
  --decay_steps=4400 \
  --graph_builder=greedy \
  --hidden_layer_sizes=200,200 \
  --learning_rate=0.08 \
  --momentum=0.85 \
  --output_path=models \
  --task_context=models/brain_pos/greedy/$PARAMS/context \
  --seed=4 \
  --training_corpus=tagged-training-corpus \
  --tuning_corpus=tagged-tuning-corpus \
  --params=200x200-0.08-4400-0.85-4
```